# How can I force objects to snap to a grid?

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I'm building a board game app using ARCore and Sceneform. My 3D models need to snap to a grid instead of being placed anywhere. Imagine a chess board.
*How do I do that?*

I copied the classes `TransformableNode` and `TranslationController` to modify them. In `TranslationController`, the coordinates are set in the variable `desiredLocalPosition` using `Vector3`.
To my understanding I should be able to do an integer division of the coordinates so that my objects can only jump a specific distance.

```
this.desiredLocalPosition = new Vector3(pose.tx(), pose.ty(), pose.tz());

float X = (int) (pose.tx()/0.05f) * 0.05f;
float Y = pose.ty(); //i don't care about vertical
float Z = (int) (pose.tz()/0.05f) * 0.05f;

this.desiredLocalPosition.set(X,Y,Z);
```

Sadly this only works *while I'm dragging* the objects and ignores it when they're actually placed.

Since I'm a student I'm pretty much a noob programmer though. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you maybe add a short video/gif of the behaviour you're seeing? It would also help to see how you've modified the `TranslationController` class; have you changed the `onContinueTransformation()` or `updatePosition()` methods?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated `onContinueTransformation()` with the code in my question. 
I also tried to make a video, sorry for the crappy quality.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAAkYcDBlnw&list=WL  

So the code seems to work while I'm actually dragging the models, but when I let them go they still jump to the last finger contact position, if you get what I mean.

Comment: Nice one! I think I understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you've modified the `TranslationController#onContinueTransformation()` method but not the `TranslationController#onEndTransformation()` method.

The `onEndTransformation()` method is responsible for setting a new anchor based on the last `HitResult` detected at the end of the drag gesture. The gridlocked position you're setting as you go in `onContinueTransformation()` is being overridden by this new anchor.

Simply removing the logic in the `onEndTransformation()` method will enable the behaviour you're looking for.

Answer relevant for `sceneform-ux:1.5.1`.

P.S: A more workable solution to the boardgame experience you're trying to create may be to create the board as a grid of `Node`s and attach the game piece to the closest eligible `Node` to the `lastArHitResult` in `onEndTransformation()`. This would give you the flexibility of defining whatever boardspace you wished and reusing the same custom `TransformationController`, as well as creating a better "snap-to-space" user experience that happens only at the end of their drag motion.

Comment: You can see some working code here - https://github.com/AlgoRyan/arcore-design-experiments/tree/stackoverflow/53525589_snap-objects-to-grid.

Comment: Awesome, I think that's what I'm looking for. Your code works like I had in mind. Your P.S. suggestion might be a better idea though, how would you go about that? I'll mark the question as solved for now..

Comment: Happy to help. Implementing that board idea would I suspect be somewhat involved, but ultimately much more flexible and consistent. I would start off by creating a custom `BoardSpaceNode` and rewriting the `TranslationController#onEndTransformation()` method to attach the dragged game piece to the closest detected `BoardSpaceNode`, probably within a limited distance. You could then look at reimplementing your change to the `TranslationController#onContinueTransformation()` method to reflect the new approach. Beyond that I'll leave it up to you to figure out. Good luck! :)